# Swift Core Data is saving to /dev/null so it is in memory only

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm using Swift 4 and the NSPersistentContainer for a very simple data model. I have 1 entity and several attributes plus one index.
When I first created this the app was saving the data in a real store. Then I added one attribute and the index and setup to migrate automatically.
Now the CoreData debug output shows me:
CoreData: annotation: Connecting to sqlite database file at "/dev/null"
Because of this my data is not saved between sessions.
Is there a way to specify the sqlite db file? 
Can I get back to the old file?

```
var dataContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
  let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyProject")
  // Auto migrate data to new version
  let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
  description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
  description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
  container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]

  container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
  if let error = error {
    let msg = "\(error)"
    os_log("dataContainer: loadPersistentStores Error = %@", msg)
  }
  })
  container.viewContext.name = "MyProject"
  return container
}()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you instantiate your NSPersistentStoreDescription you have the option of passing in a URL. Here's a link to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstoredescription/1640563-init), and here's [a well explained post](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2017/07/10/using-an-existing-sqlite-store-with-nspersistentcontainer/) on the topic

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "NameOfDataModel")

let storeURL = try! FileManager
        .default
        .url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        .appendingPathComponent("NameOfDataModel.sqlite")

let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)
container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [storeDescription]
```

Comment: Thank you, se_puede_dev! I was able to use this approach to connect to the sqlite db and now it saves data between sessions.

Comment: You're welcome. Be sure to mark an answer as correct if it solved your problem

Comment: @Nieuwsma Since you're creating `storeURL` with the default DataModel name (i.e. `"NameOfDataModel"`), you don't need to explicitly create `"NameOfDataModel.sqlite"` using `FileManager` - as the container would, by default, be creating the same.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're creating `storeURL` with the default DataModel name (i.e. `"NameOfDataModel"`), you don't need to explicitly create `"NameOfDataModel.sqlite"` using `FileManager` - as the `container` would, by default, be creating the same.

Hence, you can utilize that default `"NameOfDataModel.sqlite"` location (i.e. `URL`) to create the `storeDescription` instance, as follows:

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "NameOfDataModel")

if let storeURL = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.last?.url
{
    let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)

    // Setting Migration Flags
    storeDescription.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true 
    storeDescription.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true

    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [storeDescription]
}
```

**PS:** Since the **default value** for the aforementioned Migration flags/keys is `true`, this all might just be overkill.

**Documentation:**
[shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstoredescription/1640623-shouldinfermappingmodelautomatic)

[shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstoredescription/1640566-shouldmigratestoreautomatically)